# Index out of bounds issue with number systems code

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I am currently having an issue with a problem where my java index is out of bounds. The specific error is inside my binaryToDecimal method and is `Index 32 out of bounds for length 32`. I have tried to reorganize my code as in declaring the `int binaryVal[] = new int[32];` as a global variable to fix the error but it does not work. How do I fix this issue?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberConverter {

    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   

    static boolean success;
    static String originalNum;
    static int value = 0;
    static int choice = 0;
    static int intNum = 0;
    static int remainder;
    static char [] valueBinaryArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        greeting();
        getOriginalNumber();
        getOutputType();
        //checkValidInput();

        if (value == 2 && choice == 3) {
            decimalToHex();
        }
        else if (value == 3 && choice == 2) {
            hexToDecimal();
        }
        else if (value == 2 && choice == 1) {
            decimalToBinary();
        }
        else if (value == 1 && choice == 2) {
            binaryToDecimal();
        }

    }

    public static void greeting() {

        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the number systems converter");
        System.out.println("Below you will be givin options as to what numbers you'd like to convert");
        System.out.println("");

    } 

    public static String getOriginalNumber() { 

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");

        originalNum = input.next();

        System.out.println("What type of number is this?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Binary");
        System.out.println("2. Decimal");
        System.out.println("3. Hexadecimal");

        value = input.nextInt();

        return originalNum;

    }

    public static void getOutputType() {

        System.out.println("Which number system would you like to convert to?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Binary");
        System.out.println("2. Decimal");
        System.out.println("3. Hexadecimal");

        choice = input.nextInt();

    }

    public static void checkValidInput() {




    }

    public static void decimalToHex() {

        int intNum = Integer.valueOf(originalNum);

        String str2 = "";

        char hex[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

        while (choice > 0) {

            remainder = intNum % 16;
            str2 = hex[remainder] + str2;
            intNum = intNum/16;

        }

    }

    public static void hexToDecimal() {

        int intNum = Integer.valueOf(originalNum);

        int counter = 0;

        String hexVal = "";

        int digit;

        while (choice > 0) {
            digit = intNum % 16;

            switch (digit) {
            case 1:
                hexVal+="F"; break;
            case 2:
                hexVal+="E"; break;
            case 3:
                hexVal+="D"; break;
            case 4:
                hexVal+="C"; break;
            case 5:
                hexVal+="B"; break;
            case 6:
                hexVal+="A"; break;
            default:
                hexVal+=Integer.toString(digit);          
            }

            intNum = intNum/16;

        }

        for (counter = hexVal.length()-1; counter>=0; counter--)
            System.out.print(hexVal.charAt(counter));

    }

    public static void decimalToBinary() {

        int intNum = Integer.valueOf(originalNum);

        int counter = 0;

        int binaryVal[] = new int[32];

        while (choice > 0) {
            binaryVal[counter++] = intNum % 2;
            intNum = intNum/2;

        }

        for (int i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(binaryVal[i]);

        }

    }

    public static void binaryToDecimal() {

        int intNum = Integer.valueOf(originalNum);

        int counter = 0;

        int binaryVal[] = new int[32];

        while (choice > 0) {
            binaryVal[counter++] = intNum % 2;
            intNum = intNum/2;

        }        

        for (int i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(binaryVal[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your code. Learn the basics of debugging so you can execute your code step by step and understand why you are getting an error.

Comment: Java arrays are 0 based, so if your array size is 32, then only 0-31 are valid indexes.

Comment: The while (choice > 0) {} loops will either run forever or not at all because don't modify choice inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with 32 items the first one is index 0 and the last one is index 31.  Trying to access the item at position 32 goes out of the range of the array which is why you get an array index out of bounds exception.

To see the output I would suggest maybe make the array 33 big instead of 32.  It's not a proper fix but you should be able to see what it is doing.

If it still goes out of bounds I'd have a closer look at your while loop end condition.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the while loop suggestion? I tried the 33 big array and that didn't work

Comment: If increasing the size of the array didn't 'fix' the array out of bounds problem then you have a more fundamental issue than a 'mere' off-by-one error.

Try breaking the logic down into smaller steps, and identifying what line of code throws the exception and why.

Answer (score 0):

so what is causing your error is your condition in your for statement. Currently, you are just checking if `choice >= 0` the problem with this check is that it allows the for statement to go beyond the length of the array you have specified (32). In order to fix this error, you simply need to add another check to make sure the for loop cannot go beyond the length of the array you have specified. This can be done by adding this statement into your for loop: `counter < binaryVal.length`. This should prevent the for loop from going beyond the length of your array and you shouldn't run into any errors. Your final code for your binaryToDecimal method should look like this:

```
public static void binaryToDecimal() {

    int intNum = Integer.valueOf(originalNum);

    int counter = 0;

    int binaryVal[] = new int[32];

    while (choice > 0 && counter < binaryVal.length) {
        binaryVal[counter++] = intNum % 2;
        intNum = intNum/2;
    }

    for (int i = counter-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(binaryVal[i]);
    }

}
```